# integer division

Tags: erlang, integer, division

By definition the integer division returns the quotient.

Why `4613.9145 div 100.` gives an error ("bad argument") ?

Answer (score 17):

For `div` the arguments need to be integers. `/` accepts arbitrary numbers as arguments, especially floats. So for your example, the following would work:

```
1> 4613.9145 / 100.  
46.139145
```

To contrast the difference, try:

```
2> 10 / 10.
1.0

3> 10 div 10.
1
```

Documentation: http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html

---

Update: [Integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html), sometimes denoted `\`, can be defined as:

```
a \ b = floor(a / b)
```

So you'll need a floor function, which isn't in the standard lib.

```
% intdiv.erl
-module(intdiv).
-export([floor/1, idiv/2]).

floor(X) when X < 0 ->
    T = trunc(X),
    case X - T == 0 of
        true -> T;
        false -> T - 1
    end;

floor(X) -> 
    trunc(X) .

idiv(A, B) ->
    floor(A / B) .
```

Usage:

```
$ erl
...
Eshell V5.7.5  (abort with ^G)
> c(intdiv).
{ok,intdiv}
> intdiv:idiv(4613.9145, 100).
46
```

Comment: I don't agree: the result is 46, not 46.139145. div = integer division, / = floating point division

Comment: whatever you propose, it's illogic. trunc(N/100) gives the result. The div function seems to  not respect the definition of the integer division.

Comment: @Bertaud: Ok, sorry, didn't mean to confuse anything here. But then, try to rephrase your question, so that answers can be more targeted. Do you want the integer part of a `float / int` division, the rounded part, the floor, the ceil? You get a bad argument error, because the arguments to the operations need to be of a certain type, and in your example, that isn't satisfied.

Comment: @Bertaud: Your question is interesting, maybe you suspect an inconsistency here. Try to express that in your question, make it more interesting, get more people to look at it and possibly a better answer than mine.

Comment: I just want to make the integer division of two numbers ! And the integer division is defined in mathematic: return the quotient of the result. What could I add ? Maybe has erlang another definition ?

Comment: @Bertaud: Updated my post, see if you like it.

Comment: The question was not: write me a module simulating the integer division !!! Nevertheless, thank you for your work

Answer (score 5):

Integer division in Erlang, `div`, is defined to take two integers as input and return an integer. The link you give in an earlier comment, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html, only uses integers in its examples so is not really useful in this discussion. Using `trunc` and `round` will allow you use any arguments you wish.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know quite what you mean by "definition."  Language designers are free to define operators however they wish.  In Erlang, they have defined `div` to accept only integer arguments.

If it is the design decisions of Erlang's creators that you are interested in knowing, you could email them.  Also, if you are curious enough to sift through the (remarkably short) grammar, you can find it [here](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/dev/lib/stdlib/src/erl_parse.yrl). Best luck!

Comment: yes and no. Read again http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html . Of course you can define the expression (1 == 1) as false but you trouble all people with that.

Comment: The types of a and b in that link aren't defined.  I think it's strongly implied by the example which uses integers and expresses the intermediate result as a fraction that a and b are integers.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're looking for, @Bertaud.  Regardless of how it's defined elsewhere, Erlang's `div` only works on integers.  You can convert the arguments to integers before calling `div`:

```
trunc(4613.9145) div 100.
```

or you can use `/` instead of `div` and convert the quotient to an integer afterward:

```
trunc(4613.9145 / 100).
```

And `trunc` may or may not be what you want- you may want `round`, or floor or ceiling (which are not defined in Erlang's standard library, but aren't hard to define yourself, as miku did with `floor` above).  That's part of the reason Erlang doesn't assume something and do the conversion for you.  But in any case, if you want an integer quotient from two non-integers in Erlang, you have to have some sort of explicit conversion step somewhere.